# Display Multiple Markers with Google Maps and React Js ES6

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6

I am able to display one marker but when I map create new google.maps.Marker inside my loop nothing is returned. Has anyone encoutnered this before? Code Below and codepen attached.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pezqKq?editors=0010

```
class GMap extends React.Component {
  state = { zoom: 10 };

  static propTypes() {
    initialCenter: React.PropTypes.objectOf(React.PropTypes.number).isRequired
  }

    render() {
    return <div className="GMap">
      <div className='UpdatedText'>
        <p>Current Zoom: { this.state.zoom }</p>
      </div>
      <div className='GMap-canvas' ref="mapCanvas">
      </div>
    </div>
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // create the map, marker and infoWindow after the component has
    // been rendered because we need to manipulate the DOM for Google =(
    this.map = this.createMap()
    this.marker = this.createMarker()
    this.infoWindow = this.createInfoWindow()
    // have to define google maps event listeners here too
    // because we can't add listeners on the map until its created
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', ()=> this.handleZoomChange())
  }

  // clean up event listeners when component unmounts
  componentDidUnMount() {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'zoom_changed')
  }

  createMap() {
    let mapOptions = {
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
      center: this.mapCenter()
    }
    return new google.maps.Map(this.refs.mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }

  mapCenter() {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(
      this.props.initialCenter.lat,
      this.props.initialCenter.lng
    )
  }
createMarker() {
const navLinks = [
        {location: 'Bondi Beach', lat: -33.890542, long: 151.274856},
        {location: 'Coogee Beach', lat: -33.923036, long: 151.259052},
        {location: 'Cronulla Beach', lat: -34.028249, long: 151.157507},
        {location: 'Manly Beach', lat: -33.80010128657071, long: 151.28747820854187}
    ];
    navLinks.map((b, i) => {
            return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(b.lat, b.long),
            map: this.map
            })
      console.log(b.long)
        })
  }

  createInfoWindow() {
    let contentString = "<div class='InfoWindow'>I'm a Window that contains Info Yay</div>"
    return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      map: this.map,
      anchor: this.marker,
      content: contentString
    })
  }

  handleZoomChange() {
    this.setState({
      zoom: this.map.getZoom()
    })
  }
}

var initialCenter = { lng: -90.1056957, lat: 29.9717272 }

ReactDOM.render(<GMap initialCenter={initialCenter} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `createMarker` you aren't actually returning anything. You need to return the `navLinks.map`. You also aren't seeing that console.log because you have it below the return statement in the map.

```
return navLinks.map((b, i) => {
  console.log(b.long)
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(b.lat, b.long),
    map: this.map
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Still no dice. codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqbZyW?editors=0010

Comment: can you clarify what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Multiple markers being displayed based off the lat and long cords in the array.

Comment: Did you look in Australia? There are 4 markers there. Your coordinates must be off somewhere.

Comment: This error is: Error: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number. Not if the cords are correct

Comment: it looks like you flipped some stuff in `createMarker` and `mapCenter`. Try changing it back to the first codepen link you gave me